# Not able to use exec command to use ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am researching over ffmpeg usage for quite a while and seemed little confusing to me. Finally I found that exec command of PHP could help in execution of ffmpeg command if ffmpeg is installed on the system . I created the php script below:

```
  exec("ffmpeg -i C:\Users\sameeksha\Downloads\v.mp4 -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 C:\FFMPEG\video.flv", $output, $return);

     if($return) {
        echo "created ".$output;     
    }
    else 
        echo "not ".$output;
```

The same command run from command line is creating the converted video, but when I run it as a PHP script it does not. I even installed dll files for ffmpeg but still did not work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using the full path to the ffmpeg file. When run from a web server (ex: apache), commands are run from the web server user (ex: a user named "apache"). It is possible that the user apache can't see the ffmpeg file. When using the command line, the script is run under the user that ran the command, which is likely your account, which means that it can see the file because it was added to your path environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in a double quoted string.

Example: `C:\FFMPEG\video.flv` needs to be `C:\\FFMPEG\\video.flv`

Or just use slashes:
`C:/FFMPEG/video.flv`

You can also enclose your command in apostrophes rather than quotes, as the apostrophe inhibits escape sequences providing `\` is not the last character in your input.

```
exec('ffmpeg -i ... ',  $output, $return);
```